# how to wait a value to return if it is not a promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

for example, there is an asynchronous function that i don't develop myself, but I know for a random time(in a few seconds) that function will return a value.
Is that any way to wait for the return if it doesn't return a promise?

Comment: Usually, you specify a callback function that gets called once the function has finished. I strongly recommend *not* to encapsulate an asynchronous function in a synchronous function with some ugly timeouts etc.

Comment: Show us the actual async code that you didn't develop yourself and we can show a real answer.  Without that, all we can do is make guesses and anything that "polls" for a response is the ugly, inefficient way to do things.  We need to see the actual code to make a solid recommendation or the right way to do things.

Answer (score 3):

Not as such.

You could write a wrapper function that returns a promise which polls until it gets a result.

The promise would then call the function you didn't write repeatedly (e.g. with `setInterval`) until it returned a value and then pass it to resolve.

```
function wrap_function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
         var interval = setInterval(function () {
             var result = the_origional_function();
             if (result) {
                 clearInterval(interval);
                 resolve(result);
             }
         }, 2000);
    });
}
```

(Assuming I'm interpreting the statement "in a few seconds) that function will return a value" correctly)

Comment: @GlassMan - Do NOT do this.  This is not the right way to solve this problem.  When you show us the actual code with the async operation in it, we can offer a good way to solve this problem.  Async hacks are a mess.  Do not use them.  To make solid, reliable, maintainable code, learn to solve async problems the right way and never use a hack.  Modify other people's code in your project if needed to solve things the right way.